# Why does eval("assert(True)") fail in python?

Tags: python, eval, assert

Look at this:

```
>>> eval("assert(True)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    assert(True)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Evaling other functions like this works fine:

```
>>> eval("str(5)")
'5'
```

So why does evaling assert fail??

Comment: `eval` parses and executes expressions, not arbitrary instructions. You want `exec`.

Answer (score 6):

`eval` is for expressions. `assert` is a statement. You seem to think it's a function, [but it's not](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement).

You could `exec` an assert, if you wanted to for some reason.

```
this = silly = []
exec('assert this is silly')
```

Comment: If assert is a statement why does it allow open and close parenthesis after it?

Comment: @SaqibAli `assert` does not even know about those parentheses in the grammar, again because it is a simple statement. `(True) == True`